# how to refresh a page in IndexedStack - flutter

Tags: flutter

I used an indexedStack for my bottom navbar pages to prevent a page from reloading each time I open it and save it's state, but the thing is I need to make another page do the exact opposite, and being refreshed each time I open it. how can I do it?

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: there is no error! I just wanna know how to do it

Comment: you will mostly state-management like proivder/riverpod/bloc on project work. also implementation of `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` will work. there are other cases depend on widget.